# Matrix representation of Hamiltonian - Issues with the tensor product

Tags: tensor-calculus, hamiltonian

I am struggling with the following problem:

Consider the Hamiltonian:

$$ \hat H = \sum_{ij} \Gamma_{ij} (\hat S_i \times \hat S_j) + \sum_i B^z_i S^z_i + \sum_{ij} J_{ij} (\hat S_i \cdot \hat S_j)$$

where $\hat S_i$ is a spin operator, $\Gamma_{ij}$ and $J_{ij}$ some interactions and $B^z$ an external magnetic field oriented along the z axis.

I would like to obtain the matrix representation of this Hamiltonian.

The first contribution is a cross product and I expect terms like:
$\epsilon_{ijk} \hat S_j \hat S_k $
The product between the spins operator is the usual product column by row? I shall obtain therefore a sum of 2x2 matrices.

About the third contribution: it shall be interpreted as tensor product of the $\hat S_i$ acting of the first particle with $\hat S_j$ acting on the second particle. Therefore I expect a 4x4 matrix.

It seems I am missing something, since the three contributions provide different size of matrices. May I have some hint about it?

Many thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

If you have $N$ sites with $N$ spin-1/2 operators  $S_1,\ldots, S_N$ Your hamiltonian acts on the tensor product space
$$
{\mathcal H}=V_1\otimes V_2\otimes V_3\otimes \cdots  \otimes V_N, 
$$
where $V_n$ is the 2-dimensional space on which the $n$-th spin acts.  This tensor-product space has dimension $2^N$, so all your matrices will have size  $2^N\times 2^N$.

The total space is spanned by states
$$
|s_1,s_2,\ldots s_N\rangle, \quad s_i=\pm 1/2
$$

For example
$$
(S_3)_z =    {\mathbb I}\otimes {\mathbb I}\otimes (\sigma_z/2) \otimes {\mathbb I}\otimes\ldots \otimes {\mathbb I}, \quad \text{(N factors) }
$$
acts on $|s_1,s_2,\ldots s_N\rangle$ to give
$$
(S_3)_z|s_1,s_2,\ldots s_N\rangle= s_3 |s_1,s_2,\ldots s_N\rangle
$$

The product of spins are, for example
$$
(S_2)\cdot (S_3) = \sum_{i=1}^3  {\mathbb I}\otimes (\sigma_i/2)\otimes (\sigma_i/2) \otimes {\mathbb I}\otimes\ldots \otimes {\mathbb I}, \quad \text{(N factors) } 
$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

I am familiar with the definition of tensor product, but my doubt deals with the cross product of operators. I expect it to give a rank 1 tensor that should describe one particle Hilbert space. Is this correct? 

$$ S_i \cdot S_j = \epsilon_{ijk} S_k $$

This should be read as: 

$$ S_i  = {\mathbb I} \otimes {\mathbb I}  \otimes {\mathbb I}  \otimes \ldots  \otimes S_i  \otimes \ldots  \otimes {\mathbb I} $$

Comment: No.  the cross product has spins acting  different sites and so has nothing to do with the usual matrix product. It is still a $2^N$- by-$2^N$  matrix. It is not acting on a single one-particle space

Comment: Of course you can use Clebsch Gordan's to combine  two sites into one spin one site.  Is that what you mean to do?  That combined site  might be useful if the $\Gamma_{ij}$ and the $J_{ij}$'s never overlap so you have an assembly of paired sites.